# has_many :through association, "No Method Error" in rails console in shell, NoMethodError: undefined method for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, sorting

I am working on a feature in a rails 3 app. I have a new model, called Box which has many "Product"(s).  The has_and_belongs_to_many was giving me trouble. So I made a new model called BoxProduct.  It looks like this:

```
    class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :product_ids
    has_many :box_products, :class_name => 'BoxProduct'
    has_many :products, through: :box_products
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :box_products
    end


    class BoxProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :box, :product
    belongs_to :box
    belongs_to :product
    end

    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Concerns::Notifiable
    include ThinkingSphinx::Scopes

    attr_accessible :box_ids


    has_many :box_products
    has_many :boxes, through: :box_products
    end
```

-The first issue I am running into here is: When I access a Box in the rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> b = Box.first
Box Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "boxes".* FROM "boxes" LIMIT 1
=> #<Box id: 1, name: "Test", image: nil, ....                        
[2] pry(main)> b.products
Product Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN
"box_products" ON "products"."id" = "box_products"."product_id"
WHERE "box_products"."box_id" = 1
=> []
[3] pry(main)> b = Box.where("id" => 2)
Box Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "boxes".* FROM "boxes" WHERE   
"boxes"."id" = 2
=> [#<Box id: 2, name: "Yoo", image: "image.jpeg" ....
[4] pry(main)> b.products
NoMethodError: undefined method `products' for # 
<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f3b68c30208>
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
```

However, in the CMS, in the box view page, @box.products returns the products for each box in a table as implement, for all Box entries that I have created so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is easy to solve: Please note that `where` does not return one single object from the database, even if there was only one entry found. `where` returns an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), that acts as a list in the context of your question.

```
Box.where("id" => 2)
#=> [#<Box id: 2, ... # Note the `[` at the beginning of the line
```

And you cannot call `products` on this `Relation`, because `products` is defined on `Box`, but not on `Relation`.

You can fix this problem in different ways depending on your needs.

You could iterate and over that list and call `products` on each entry:

```
Box.where(id: 2).map(&:products)
Box.where(id: 2).includes(:products)
```

Or your could use a method that only returns a single element:

```
Box.find(2).products
Box.find_by(id: 2).products
Box.where(id: 2).take.products
Box.where(id: 2).first.products
```

Comment: Thanks again spickermann, your explanation pointed me in the right direction to review things like blocs, symbol to proc, and rails specific 'magic'